# How to maximize the total probability?

Tags: c++, math, random, probability, maximize

I want to maximize the total probability of winning in a game of random selection which is played as follows,

I have n lottery tickets and out of these n only 1 is the lucky ticket, now I have 2 option either draw a ticket or ask the master to remove some X unlucky ticket out of total tickets, X must be a multiple of k (available) and X must be smaller than total number of tickets.

If i draw an unlucky ticket master will add k unlucky tickets to the pile of tickets.

We have at max m moves to play, each move is one of the following

1. Either we draw a ticket
2. Either we ask master to remove X tickets (X is multiple of k)

I want to maximize the probability.

And output the total probability P/Q as P*Q^(-1) where Q is modular inverse of Q.

After observing and playing the game I think the total probability will be maximum only when we play the game in the following way

1. First move we draw a ticket and probability of winning is 1/n.
2. If we draw an unlucky ticket in first move k tickets are added and we can ask the master to remove k tickets in second move.
3. In third move we again draw ticket and probability of winning now is
   ((n-1)/n)*(1/n) .

Similarly if there are m moves than we can conclude that, total probability of winning is (1-((n-1)/n)^r) where we can find value of r

n

for example : 
n = 3 k = 20 m = 3

total probability is 1-(2/3)^2 = 5/9

n = 5 k = 7 m = 1

total probability of winning is = 1/5

Final output :

5*(9)^(-1) % 1000000007 = 555555560

1*(5)^(-1) % 1000000007 = 400000003

If there is other winning strategy in this game please provide it with proof and i don't have a proof for my strategy too so if you can prove my strategy i will be glad to have it as well as a psuedocode will help me to proceed.

we again put the ticket that we picked in the pile again so after drawing wrong we have n+k instead of n+k-1, and also n < k ( for the starting always)

EDIT :  Proof of my strategy

for each move we take there are 2 possibilities

**either we gain 1/n*(n-1)/n or we gain (n-1)/n*(1/n+k) + (n-1/n)*((n+k-1)/n+k)*(1/n+2*k)**

now after solving both sides we get to equation 1/n left hand side and right hand side is (2*n+3*k-1)/((n+2*k)*(n+k) and i found that R.H.S is always less than or equals to R.H.S

So after further solving i get L.H.S as 2*(k^2) and R.H.S as n^2-n and as given n < k so L.H.S is always greater than R.H.s

Hence proved.

Please provide feedback for the proof.

Comment: Please show us the code you've tried so far, and explain why it doesn't do what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strategy is incorrect.  After drawing an unlucky ticket, you would ask the master to remove k tickets, but if you had *started* playing in exactly the same state, you would have picked a ticket instead.  That does not make sense, because the game has no memory of your previous moves, and the present situation should therefore always dictate the best choice.

Let **P(n,m,k)** be the probability of winning with *n* tickets, max **m** moves, and **k**, with optimal strategy.

If you pick a ticket, then the probability is **1/n + P(n+k-1, m-1, k)*(n-1)/n**.

If you don't then the probability is **P(n-k, m-1, k)**

The optimal choice is the one with best probability, and so:

**P(n,m,k) = max( 1/n + P(n+k-1, m-1, k)*(n-1)/n , P(n-k, m-1, k) )**

You can could calculate this recursively, with memoization since there are likely to be overlapping subproblems, i.e., with dynamic programming.

Comment: my solution is correct too, please have a look at my proof in recent edits and thanks for DP approach